# Make a cubic box in 3d scatter plot in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I have made the following figure in Octave using the `scatter3` function.

I would like to draw the rest of the sides of the cube in the plot (the lines `x=0,y=0`, `z=20,x=0` etc). How to do this?[image]

Comment: You can just define a line by its start- and endpoint in 3D and plot those.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot3([0,0],[0,0],[0,20],'linewidth',2,'k')
```

Draws a line between (0,0,0) and (0,0,20). Make such lines for all the sides.